# Método jQuery não está gravando no BD

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma rotina para gravar no BD. Consigo no success do AJAX, disparar um `alert`, mas não grava. Um botão que chama o método, passa os parâmetros para o método na controller e esse método grava, com um `SaveChanges()`.

Obs: Não dá nenhum tipo de erro, mas não entra no método no *controller*. Coloquei um `break` bem na primeira chave e não entra, como se não tivesse chamando. Coloquei um `Alert()` no success do AJAX e consigo disparar.
Meu botão:

```
str += '<button id="btn_Confirmar" name="btn_Confirmar" onclick=" return GravaPainelPesquisa();">Confirmar</button>';
```

Meu jQuery:

```
function GravaPainelPesquisa() {

    var parametros = {
        _cnpj: $('#txtCnpjPesquisa').val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''),
        _tecnico: $('#txtTecnicoObs').val(),
        _obs: $('#txtObservacao').val() 
    }

    $.ajax({

        url: '/Pesquisa/GravaPainelPesquisa',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
        success: function (data) {

            alert('Testando hoje, 20/06/2014');
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

E minha *controller*

```
[HttpPost]
        public void GravaPainelPesquisa(string _cnpj, string _tecnico, string _obs)
        {
            using (V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities())
            {
                T_LogCadastroPDV logcadastro = new T_LogCadastroPDV();

                DateTime _datacadastro = new DateTime();
                DateTime? _datacontrole = new DateTime();
                DateTime? _datatransacao = new DateTime();

                var resultado_log = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                    .Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => _cnpj, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                    .Where(status => status.t1.DE_Cnpj == _cnpj)
                    .Select(i => new { i.t1.DT_ControleV, i.t1.DT_TransacaoV, i.t2.DataCadastro });

                foreach (var dados in resultado_log)
                {
                    _datacadastro = dados.DataCadastro;
                    _datacontrole = dados.DT_ControleV;
                    _datatransacao = dados.DT_TransacaoV;
                }

                try
                {
                    logcadastro.DE_CnpjPDV = _cnpj;
                    logcadastro.DE_Tecnico = _tecnico;
                    logcadastro.DT_Cadastro = _datacadastro;
                    logcadastro.DT_Controle = _datacontrole;
                    logcadastro.DT_Transacao = _datatransacao;
                    logcadastro.DE_Obs = _obs;

                    db.T_LogCadastroPDV.Add(logcadastro);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    string erro = ex.Message;
                }

            }
        }
```

O problema é que estava o campo tecnico, estava com o nome trocado e como ele é required no BD, não gravava. O interessante é não entrava no catch. Usei o IE e consegui descobri, o q não estava conseguindo com o Chrome. Agora, está vindo o código e não o texto do dropdownlist. passo isso _tecnico: $('#ddlTecnico').val(), e está vindo o código. será por causa que o value é o código e não texto e eu estou pegando o val()?

Comment: é MVC ou Web API?

Comment: MVC. Uso MVC com Jquery

Comment: já tenteu testar seu endpoint com [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? Por que pode estar ocorrendo "Multiple actions were found that match the request". Code Error 500.

Comment: O problema é que estava o campo tecnico, estava com o nome trocado e como ele é required no BD, não gravava. O interessante é não entrava no catch. Usei o IE e consegui descobri, o q não estava conseguindo com o Chrome. Agora, está vindo o código e não o texto do dropdownlist. passo isso _tecnico: $('#ddlTecnico').val(), e está vindo o código. será por causa que o value é o código e não texto e eu estou pegando o val()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que pode estar havendo é "Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content web api post", onde não é possível enviar múltiplos parâmetros em uma requisição post, isso ocorre, tanto no `Web API` quanto no `MVC`.

Bem, a maneira mais simples(para mim) para contornar isto, você deve tratar os parâmetros como um único objeto, você pode:

Criar um objeto(com a estrutura dos parâmetros):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void GravaPainelPesquisa([FromBody]Params param)
    {
        var _cnpj = param._cnpj;
        var _tecnico = param._tecnico;
        var _obs = param._obs;

        // restante do seu codigo
    }

    public class Params
    {
        public string _cnpj { get; set; }
        public string _tecnico { get; set; }
        public string _obs { get; set; }
    }
```

Ou usar o tipo genérico do C# dynamic:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void GravaPainelPesquisa([FromBody]dynamic param)
    {
        var _cnpj = param._cnpj;
        var _tecnico = param._tecnico;
        var _obs = param._obs;

        // restante do seu codigo
    }
```

Já a questão de não estar salvando no banco de dados não posso lhe ajudar, pois não trabalho com EF.